# How to update the $ionicLoading with progress percent?

Tags: ionic-framework

Being working on Ionic project and using `$ionicLoading` to present the download progress (this progress need to lock the UI).
So how to update the progress percent (in text) to with `$ionicLoading` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call the `$ionicLoading.show({template: 'updated text'})` again, it will replace the next once.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the **scope** property:

```
// In your controller or us any scope you want.
$scope.uploadProgress = 0; // update this in your progress callback

// show once
$ionicLoading.show({
  scope: $scope,
  template: '<p>Saving...</p><p>{{uploadProgress}}</p><ion-spinner></ion-spinner>'
});
```